# Give docker container access to usb wireless adapter

Tags: linux, networking, docker, bridge, usb-network-adapter

I have a wireless usb adapter and I would like my docker container to use just this for the internet (not the computers own wireless adapter).

My knowledge of networking is basic so I have tried to read a lot to work out how to do this but I'm completely out of my depth.

So far I have unsuccessfully tried the following (enx582c80139263 is the usb wireless adapter):

1) create a network namespace for the container and to move the wireless adapter to that (by following [this](https://github.com/fgg89/docker-ap/wiki/Container-access-to-wireless-network-interface)):

```
sudo docker run -dit --rm --privileged --net none --name mycontainer debian
pid=$(sudo docker inspect --format '{{.State.Pid}}' mycontainer);
sudo mkdir -p /var/run/netns;
sudo ln -s /proc/$pid/ns/net /var/run/netns/$pid;
sudo ip link set dev enx582c80139263 netns $pid;
```

When I do this, the adapter no longer show an ip address when I do ifconfig. I'm not sure of the process of how the wireless adapter gets an ip address normally when in the global namespace, so I got stuck here

2) create a network namespace for the container and then creating veth pair, with one veth in the container namespace and the other in global namespace. Then I gave them ip addresses and used a bridge (brctl) to connect the wireless adapter interface to the global namespace veth.

```
sudo docker run -dit --rm --privileged --net none --name mycontainer debian
pid=$(sudo docker inspect --format '{{.State.Pid}}' mycontainer);
sudo mkdir -p /var/run/netns;
sudo ln -s /proc/$pid/ns/net /var/run/netns/$pid;
sudo ip link add veth0 type veth peer name veth1
sudo ip link set veth1 netns $pid
sudo ip netns exec $pid ifconfig veth1 10.0.0.1/24 up
sudo ifconfig veth0 10.0.0.2/24 up
sudo brctl addbr br0
sudo brctl addif br0 enx582c80139263 veth0
```

I can ping from one veth to the other before adding the global veth to the bridge, but can't after I add it. Not sure why

Also, one I connect the wireless adapter to the bridge I can't access the internet (I thought that the internet would be accessible from the in build wireless card because I am still connected to the wifi).

---

I may be going about this completely the wrong way...literally learnt about networking and docker in the past few days. Please let me know if I should be approaching this a different way

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, try your luck in the Unix & Linux site...

Comment: Thanks. I managed to get it working by following this guide: https://blogs.igalia.com/dpino/2016/04/10/network-namespaces/